# How to use parameter variables in Cursor SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a Scalar function for my web application. I want to calculate the date difference between an employee's Join Date and Resign Date.

I have got most of my code working, but I just cannot figure out how to use parameter variables in cursor.

Let say I have this block of code

```
    Declare myCursor Cursor for

    Declare @join_date datetime
    Declare @resign_date datetime
    Declare @emp_stat nvarchar(50)


    --What I have been trying to do. (Not working)
    Select @join_date = Convert(datetime, join_date), @emp_stat = Convert(datetime, emp_stat) from t_emp_info where .....
    OPEN product_cursor
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
     if (@emp_stat = 'P') 
        Begin
           //DateDiff .....

        End

  FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @join_date , @emp_stat 
  End
 Close myCursor
 DEALLOCATE myCursor;
```

I can't get this working, but what I want is I want to store the values in the parameter so I can use it in the if condition statement. Not sure how to fix this. Help will be appreciated

Comment: why are you using a cursor?

Comment: because I am trying to loop through my table to see which employee has the Resign status and present status. And Employee can resign and than come back. So I need to loop though that to get the lastest join date. Otherwise, the first day shows up in the table with the Present status will always be his first join day (not what I want) For example. Employee Join this company on 1/1/2010, then resign on 5/3/2013. Come back again on 4/5/2014. In this case, I want his join date change to 4/5/2014 not 1/1/2010.

Comment: You don;t typically ever want to loop through records. This is a poor way to program in SQL.

Comment: instead of looping, you can do something Select EmployeeID, Max(EmployeeJoinDate) group by EmployeeID. No need to loop through records.

Comment: You could also use emp_stat in the where instead of using the variable

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor names are mixed up and your assignment is in the wrong place. Try:

```
Declare myCursor Cursor for
Select join_date, emp_stat, resign_date from t_emp_info where .....

Declare @join_date datetime
Declare @resign_date datetime
Declare @emp_stat nvarchar(50)

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
INTO @join_date , @emp_stat , @resign_date

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 //Your logic here

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
INTO @join_date , @emp_stat, @resign_date
End
Close myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor;
```

However you should avoid the cursor. What is wrong with:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, MAX(join_date), case when emp_stat = 'P' then getdate() else MAX(resign_date) end) 
from t_emp_info 
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Or similar?